# Error in UK visa application

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

Can someone help me out. Someone filled a United Kingdom visit visa online application form for me. He didn't confirm from me if I was refused visa by any country and he put No. He just submitted the form last night. As I was going through the form he sent I saw No. What can I do since the form has been submitted. I need to state that I was refused a United States visa in 2015. Can I write it in the cover letter that I failed to include it. Or what do I advice I do to rectify the mistake. Am so worried right now.

Comment: Be very careful when paying someone to submit a visa application on your behalf. Their errors, carelessness, or deliberate falsehoods will affect you, not them.

Answer (score 12):

Withdraw your visa application and apply again, this time with the right details.

https://www.gov.uk/cancel-visa

Do *not* attempt to correct this as part of the cover letter etc - cover letters can get overlooked, separated from your application, misunderstood and so on.  Withdraw your application before its considered.

Comment: I applied with my wife and child. Should I withdraw theirs too. Because I want us to get a date for biometric together. And can I get a refund if I withdraw. Can I also apply immediately after withdrawing my application

Comment: If you withdraw before biometrics are taken, you get a refund - so yes, if thats your goal, and your applications are together, then you should withdraw all applications and reapply.

Comment: @Luvlyspot Please read the information in the supplied link, that answers your first question.

Comment: Please can I reapply immediately, I withdraw. Or do I need to wait for some certain period. We just submitted and paid we haven't selected a date for biometric.

Comment: The moment your application is cancelled, you can apply again.  Pretty sure this is immediate.  Refund might take some time to show up tho.